# Hadoop MultipleInputs combine in same mapper

Tags: java, hadoop

Say, we take two input files:

```
file1 content: a b c d

file2 content: b c d e
```

I want `TokenizerMapper.class` to create the result below

```
ab ac ad ae bd bc bd be cb cc cd ce db dc dd de
```

one word align to the other word
I store file1 content into an array and file2 content into an another array
and run for loop to create it .
The Problem is  How can i using `MultipleInputs` to combine two file content in the same class?

blew code has `MultipleIputs`:

```
public class WordCount {

  public static class TokenizerMapper
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
      while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(itr.nextToken());
        context.write(word, one);
      }
    }
  }

  public static class IntSumReducer
       extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                       Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      int sum = 0;
      for (IntWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
      }
      result.set(sum);
      context.write(key, result);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    //FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]), TextInputFormat.class, TokenizerMapper.class);
    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]), TextInputFormat.class, TokenizerMapper.class);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: why do you need multipeinputs for that? what is the format of the input data? MultipleInputs is used when you want to do different things in the mapper, or your input is of different format, not when you have multiple files as input. Also, a mapper cannot know the input of another mapper

Comment: Is any class will input two file and do it in the same map class ?

Comment: I do not understand your comment